# Default type font android

Tags: android, css, fonts

I'm creating the graphic part of my android application and I'm working with the fonts. The case is that I found a text font I like it and I want to use it by default, not writing  `android:typeface=""` every time.

So, is there any option to set a font to default?

Also, is there anything like css of html in android?

Answer (score 2):

There is. There are styles, you can use to design your layouts. See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

BUT: You can't use custom fonts in layout.xml neither in styles. You have to define font programmatically. For more info see: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/